Find aggregate boundary of CT scan image using MATLAB
I have a CT scan image as show here Original image, I want to separate these phases into aggregates (gray color) and voids (black color). I try do to with MATLAB adaptivethreshold and bwbinary, however the result was not good Result. Do you have any recommendation?
How to find aggregate boundary in CT scan image.
